# Why aren't my PHP-FPM children transitioning back to idle as soon as the request is complete?

Tags: php, php-fpm, kubernetes

I'm trying to debug server lockups when running a Laravel application on K8s. I've got 2 pods each with 100 static children and I'm running a load test. As expected, as the load is applied the children pick up the requests (the request is a simple homepage page load - I'm using a fresh Laravel app to rule out any app logic being the culprit) but the processes don't seem to end until they time out (currently set to 300s as per the defaults). With this behaviour, all of the children appear to stay running much longer than the request duration. Is this expected behaviour? If not, does anyone have any clue why the children are not transitioning to idle once the request has completed?

[image]

FPM Pool Config:

```
[www]

user = application
group = application

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

pm = static
pm.max_children = 100
pm.max_requests = 200

pm.status_path = /status
access.log = /docker.stdout

access.format = "[php-fpm:access] %R - %u %t \"%m %r%Q%q\" %s %f %{mili}d %{kilo}M %C%%"

slowlog = /docker.stderr
request_slowlog_timeout = 1

catch_workers_output = yes
clear_env = no

php_admin_value[error_log] = /docker.stderr
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[log_errors] = on

php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Michael Hampton I've intercepted the Laravel framework by adding the following to the top of the `/routes/web.php` file.

```php
echo("<h1>Hello Kubernetes</h1>");
die();
```

Now when performing the load test (with only one pod this time) the behaviour is much more acceptable, leading me to believe that the issue stems from the Laravel project. Because it's a fresh installation, my next step is to look into my `.env` file that I've reused from the offending project to see if there are any culprits there. Any suggestions on how else to debug this are welcome!

[image]

**UPDATE 2**
Upon removing the above interception in the framework, the requests are back to never-ending. As this looks like a Laravel issue, i'm going to take this over to StackOverflow.

[image]

Comment: I think you should be looking at Laravel here. You should at least test with an actually trivial request like `echo("<h1>Hello Kubernetes</h1>);` to rule it out.

Comment: Interesting... When I add `echo("<h1>Hello Kubernetes</h1>"); die();` to to top of `/routes/web.php` the requests behave like expected (and use many, many fewer requests)! I've added the changes to the question. Any suggestions on how to debug this? Again, the Laravel application is a fresh one that I haven't touched other than `.env` variables. Maybe that would be a good place to start.

Comment: We just do ops here. Programming is out of our scope. But you should look into what Laravel is doing. It's a pretty big framework.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your help getting this far.

Comment: @AlexGodbehere Did you ever get any information about the Laravel side of this on StackOverflow? I can see that you found that in your case the problem was tied to the Redis driver and so you just switched away from it, but, I'm seeing the same problem and we're not using Redis anywhere.

Comment: @philomory I'm afraid not. I moved to a self-hosted Redis instance (instead of managed by DO) and the problem has not resurfaced in nearly two years. Sorry that's not very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that encounters the same problem, it was due to my Redis connection. By moving to `database` drivers for session and cache the FPM processes are closing as expected. I'm unsure why the Redis driver was keeping connections open but I unfortunately don't have the capacity to debug it at the minute.

Comment: Can you explain more clear how did you change the setup. Was it Redis config or Nextcloud or PHP-FPM ?
It seems I have similar problem.